# Problem with using mono to run .exe files in kali linux

Tags: mono

When doing mono file.exe
i get this error

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Comment: Stop using Mono for WinForms as you get more issues than ease. To write a Linux desktop app, use other technologies.

Comment: FYI, I wrote about that a while ago https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea